# Curl request from Europe based AWS EC2 gets US version of website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an AWS EC2 instance in the Frankfurt region which I am using to monitor a website. However when I do a curl request for the website content it returns the content from the US version of that website, rather than the European version as expected. When I check the IP of the instance against various IP location services it always returns Germany, so I presume that any geolocation the website uses should return Germany. I am wondering if there are any likely reasons why I am getting the US version and how I can make sure to get the European version instead.

Comment: When you say that it returns US version, are you saying that it is returning an English-language version from the Germany server, or are you saying that it is getting content from the actual US server that is _not_ present on the Germany server?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm monitoring the price of some products from the website and normally if I access the website from Europe I get Euro prices, however from the AWS EC2 instance in Frankfurt I see prices in USD. The content is delivered from the same server, it just appears to decide that the EC2 instance is situated in the US.

Comment: It might be based on the locale settings used by your browser, rather than the IP address of the request. You can test this by using `curl` from your own computer (rather than the browser) to see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I checked with curl from my own computer and it gets the version with euro prices, so it's not related to anything the browser is setting. I'm not sure what else to consider.